# Git Rebasing is not showing feature/local branch changes while resolving conflicts

Tags: git

I'm trying to check how duplicate commits are formed in GIT. In that process I got struck at one point.

Created Local Repo & file colors.txt

```
VIOLET -> C1 & Pushed the changes in local master to github
```

Now created the feature branch based on C1 & added below contents

```
OTHER COLORS
------------
RED   -> C2 & Pushed the changes from local feat to feat branch in github
BLACK -> C2 & Pushed the changes from local feat to feat branch in github
```

Now in the local branch master created one more commit

```
VIOLET   -> C1
INDIGO   -> C3 & Pushed the changes from local master to master branch in github
BLUE     -> C3 & Pushed the changes from local master to master branch in github
```

Now I have moved to feat branch and ran the rebase command (**git rebase master**)

- Asked me to resolve the conflicts
- Here I see the changes coming from master branch but my local branch changes (Addition of red & black - C2) are not visible.

How should I proceed now If my local branch changes are not visible while resolving the conflicts? Am I missing something ?

[image]

Comment: Could you show us the conflict markers? And note that pushing has no bearing on this. Only the local repository matters.

Comment: @Schwern updated the question

Comment: Did you add the header in one commit and the colors in another?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about "duplicate commits", but are you aware that `git rebase` does create new copies of all the rebased commits?

Comment: You are not showing us enough information. It would really help if you would show the output of `git log --graph --all`

Comment: @Schwern Yeah ! I found the solution. For header commit it asked me to resolve the conflicts then I have done added the changes to staging area then ran command git rebase --continue, then I see now the other commit conflict. I have one question here - For every commit of feature branch do we need to resolve the conflicts ?

Comment: @Shivaay Yes, each commit in feature will be "merged" separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your conflict and the commit message, I suspect you made *two* commits in your feature branch. One to add the "OTHER COLORS" header and a second to add red and black.

Unlike a merge, rebase merges each commit separately. This simulates as if you'd written the branch on top of the new master branch. First it will merge the "OTHER COLORS" commit with master, which generates a conflict. *Then* it will merge the next commit to add red and black on the result. This might result in another conflict.